# MySql Workbench catalog view width problem

Tags: mysql, diagram, workbench

When I am creating EER Diagram on the left side I have the view "Catalog" with a list of databases and tables, but can't see full names of it (**mydb_long_database_name** and **my_test_customer_long_table_name**). Width of this view is limited and I don't know how to change this. I attached screenshot

PS: I am using MySql Workbench 8.0.15 and Ubuntu 18.04.4

[image: screenshort 1]

[image: screenshort 2]

Comment: Hi! What version of Ubuntu and MySQL Workbench are you using?

Comment: MySql Workbench 8.0.15 and Ubuntu 18.04.4